# Why geometry('value') method in python takes strings values?

Tags: python, object, user-interface, tkinter, methods

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
```

i just wanted to know why geometry('value') method in python takes strings values, but instead it should take numbers like integer.

Comment: What kind of advice or suggestion do you need? You just asked for a rationale.

Comment: btw first of you shouldn't import everything from any module (basically don't use `*` when importing), but also it is quite useless to import a module twice, also it is possible to specify the width and height using integer values: `window.config(width=500, height=500)` or sth like this: `window.geometry(f'{500}x{500}')` (tho the latter obviously immediately converts that to a string)

Answer (score 3):

Tkinter is based on the programming language Tcl and the graphical toolkit Tk. Tk has its origins in the [X windowing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (also known as X11) from the 1990's.

In X11, window geometry can be specified as a string in the form of *=widthxheight±x±y*. The advantage to being a string is that it can be defined external to the code, which was important back when this format was first defined. It made it easy to customize the appearance of windows without having to modify any code.

Since it is a perfectly fine way to specify the geometry of a widget, there's no compelling reason to change it.

Answer (score 2):

The function takes a string because it is not a native Python function. It is part of the [Tk toolkit library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)), which is designed to work with multiple programming languages. The `geometry()` method is really a [Tk procedure](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.html#M42).

It started as a library for the [Tcl programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl), but now can be used from more programming languages, including Python.

Instead of using the `geometry()` method, you could just set the `width`, `height` properties directly, which *are* numbers. Note however that the `geometry` string also lets you set the window position, but there are no properties you can set to do the same.